# CURL/PHP - Trying to parse HTML DOM Element but receiving error

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-goletto-mens-astro-turf-trainers-263244?colcode=26324408";   

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);  


    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($str);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $name  = $xpath->query('//span[@id="ProductName"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $name;

?>
```

I am trying to parse the text placed in element `<span id="ProductName">TEXT here</span>` but i receive error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/sportsdi/public_html/test.php on line 28

Can you please tell me where is my mistake, i am stuck on this for hours ?
How can i get the text in this element ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your `var_dupm($xpath)` shows :- `object(DOMXPath)#2 (1) { ["document"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" }` means no data retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

`$str` is a string, not a file.

Use:

```
$doc->loadHTML( $str );
```

instead of:

```
$doc->loadHTMLFile( $str );
```

By your code, `->loadHTMLFile()` fails, consequently also `DOMXpath` initialization — based on `DOMDocument` — fails.